# Occasional spawning with full health

Tags: terraria

Today while I fought the Twins with my friends, I noticed that sometimes when I re-spawn, I don't get 100 health points like usually, but my health is instantly 400hp full even without visiting a nurse. I'm not aware of any item that would allow this. It happened approximately 1 of 3 times I died.

I include a screenshot of my current inventory/accessories from the time, when it happened. Is this a bug?

[image: my inventory]

**EDIT**

I've got my suspect no.1, it's the [mana flower](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Mana_Flower) I use. It was crafted from a [nature's gift](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Nature%27s_Gift) which used to have this ability before 1.0.6.

Comment: I've had this happen a couple times before too. I always assumed it was just a bug.

Comment: Do you also use [mana flower](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Mana_Flower) like I do? This is my suspect no.1, it was crafted from a [nature's gift](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Nature%27s_Gift) which used to have this ability before 1.0.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would assume that The Twins sometimes cause explosive damage. If you are killed by explosives, you respawn with full health.

Comment: Oh, I guess mystery solved then. I used Hellfire arrows in the fight, and few times I blew myself up with the explosion they make. And also possible the Twins cause explosive damage, too.

Comment: Ah, it's probably the Hellfire arrows then. I looked at the wiki, and it doesn't show the Twins doing any explosive damage.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you had PvP enabled, that will occasionally spawn you with full health because being KO'd by another human player causes you to not drop coins and spawn with max HP. If you play with a friend this can become an easier way to survive bosses.